# Deserializing char from xml

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'd like to know if it is possible to deserialize a char from xml into a c# object.

So I'd like to deserialize :

```
    <MyChar>a<MyChar>
```

into:

```
    [XmlElement]
    public char MyChar { get; set; }
```

I was hoping to use [XmlElement(DataType = "char")] but char is not a [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype.aspx) type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said , it not be supported.

But you can implement by this way ...

```
    public string MyCharString { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public char MyChar
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToChar(MyCharString);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your property as a `string` type and limit its length to 1 in the setter. Don't consider using `byte` as this will not allow you to handle unicode characters.